# How to update rows in Streaming Dataset in PowerBI?

Tags: python, sql, powerbi

I created a Streaming Dataset in PowerBI. This dataset is used to analyze data of whole day so I activated the Historical data analysis (If not, the streaming dataset only show data for short time)

```
[
 {
  "HOUR" :98.6,
  "WAREHOUSEID" :"AAAAA555555",
  "STOREID" :"AAAAA555555",
  "STAFFID" :"AAAAA555555",
  "ITEMID" :"AAAAA555555",
  "INVENTQTY" :98.6,
  "PACKQTY" :98.6,
  "PICKINGSTATUS" :"AAAAA555555",
  "DATEID" :"2020-07-14T03:53:12.047Z",
  "RECID" :"AAAAA555555"
 }
]
```

I push the data from SQL Server to PowerBI base on the modified datetime, each 10 minutes I query all the rows which are new from the last modified datetime and push all to PowerBI, then save the new modified datetime and continue.

The problem is, PICKINGSTATUS has two state `"Pending"` and `"Completed"`, when pushing streaming data, the value maybe change from Pending -> Completed so the row must be updated for the dashboard to be updated. But now, PowerBI doesn't seem to update the rows, it adds duplicate row with only different PICKINGSTATUS value and so that the dashboard is wrong.

How can I make it right? I tried some research but I can't barely find the solutions.

Thank you for your help, have a good day!

Comment: Power BI is not a database. You can't update these rows, neither can selectively delete some of them. The only supported operations are `delete all rows` and `insert these rows`.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have solved the problem by using Selenium to automatically turn off/on the Historic Data Analysis to delete all the data and push whole new updated data to the PowerBI. Its definitely not the best way but it works for now!